# Encoding Line Feed Characters in the value of a NSXMLElement's attribute

Tags: xml, cocoa, nsxmlparser, nsxmldocument, nsxmlelement

The comment field of an XML database I'm reading and writing is stored as the attribute of an NSXMLElement. One entry contains a line feed (0x0a) character. These are encoded by a non NSXML encoder in the document I'm parsing as `&#xA;` and get parsed correctly by NSXML. They result in the NSString containing the unicode value 0x0a 0x00 in memory (intel byte ordering).

For example:

```
<INFO BITRATE="192000" GENRE="Podcast" COMMENT="Test &amp; More Test &#xA;&#xA;After the Line Feeds"</INFO>
```

When writing this NSString back out as the value of an NSXMLElement's attribute, it does not get encoded back and results in the following being output to the xml file:

```
 <INFO BITRATE="192000" GENRE="Podcast" COMMENT="Test &amp; More Test 

After the Line Feeds"</INFO>
```

which of course does not get parsed properly upon re-reading the file again.

It seems like node options like `NSXMLNodePreserveCharacterReferences` or `NSXMLNodePreserveEntities` should be the way to go but it doesn't seem to help in any way.

I must be missing the obvious but I've been stuck on this all day.

Comment: Did you use those options when reading or when writing?

Comment: I first had no options (apart from NSXMLNodePrettyPrint on the whole document when writing).

Comment: I have `NSXMLNodePrettyPrint` on the whole document and `NSXMLNodePreserveCharacterReferences | NSXMLNodePreserveEntities` on the comments attribute node when writing.

I do not have any options when reading. Just using `[[anElement attributeForName:@"Comments"] stringValue]` on the node.

Comment: The `Preserve` options are only useful when reading/parsing XML. This is in the documentation. Look up `NSXMLNodePreserveCharacterReferences` and scroll down to the discussion section. Your other option is to do the substitution yourself using standard `NSString` methods and then set it on the `NSXMLNode` using `-setStringValue:resolvingEntities:`, passing `NO`.

Comment: I will give that a try, thank you. It's odd that it isn't consistent with its read/write behavior (i.e it converts &#xA; upend reading but does not convert it back upon writing).

Comment: I have used one of my support requests with Apple to try and diagnose the problem. I will report back here any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked with Apple, this is a known issue with NSXMLDocument and it has now been filed as a bug report.

Suggested workaround include using libxml2 for the time being.

I will post a comment if I see this fixed in a future release.

Comment: For future reference, this is currently being tracked by apple as rdar://problem/7388696

Answer (score -1):

Apple says:

> The options with “Preserve” in their names are applicable only when external sources of XML are parsed; they have no effect on node objects that are programmatically created. Other options are used in initialization and output methods of NSXMLDocument; see the NSXMLDocument reference documentation for details.`
>   It dose not work for me, I think it is a bug.

I solved this problem with KissXML.